# Replacing the colon operator with an equivalent vectorizable solution

Tags: matlab, octave

My current code does something like this:

```
for offset = 0:0.9:max_offset :
    x = offset:step_size:max_value;

    [...]

end
```

I would like to vectorize and remove the for loop to make it faster, but if I try making `offset` a vector, the colon operator on the second line is equivalent to doing

```
x = offset(1):step_size:max_value;
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve the desired result, i.e. get

```
x = [ 0:step_size:max_value;
      0.9:step_size:max_value;
      1.8:step_size:max_value; ... ]
```

assuming I don't know `max_offset`, and therefore the length of number of rows I want in `x`?

Comment: Since length of x would vary from iteration to iteration, you can't store all x's into a matrix form and that would mostly mean using cell arrays, which won't really help with performance, unless you actually want `x` as `cells`. So, rather you must look to make the rest of the code inside the loop efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each vector will be a different size, they wont fit in a matrix easily. You will have to put them in a cell array, like so:

```
offset=0:.9:max_offset;
x=arrayfun(@(k) k:step_size:max_value,offset,'UniformOutput',false)
```

and rather than referring to rows of `x` by `x(i,:)` for a matrix, you would do `x{i}` to get the right vector out.

Comment: Is this faster than just keeping the for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure. For smaller sized problems it could be, but the performance isn't likely to be much difference. Actually, I've just thought of another way. Do `x=0:step_size:max_value` then instead of getting the `i`-th row of the `x` matrix, `x(i,:)`, you can just do `x(i:end)` to get the values that you want.